# How do I get child class checkboxes to change state when using a parent class checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with my script, when trying to get the child classes to disable and uncheck if the parent class is unchecked.  It currently makes no change that can be seen on the page.
  I am also trying to get the child classes to refer to each other at the same time, if the previous one is unchecked, I want the following ones to be unchecked and disabled.  If it is checked, then the next one is enabled, but the following ones from that disabled until the proceeding one is checked.
  Lastly I am trying to get this script to run once the page has completely loaded and also when a checkbox is checked.
   This is dealing with nested tables from a plugin but each section of table is set up with classes on both the outer table and inner tables.
   Anything that anyone sees to help me with this would be appreciative.  I am in way over my head dealing with JavaScript.

I have the page load with test data currently, I have introduced validation errors currently.  Though it is not acting how I think it should work.
   Currently I have three functions  that are working together to bring about the results.  I can step though the code during a debug and it is going through all three functions, but the page itself is not showing any changes.
   While all the data is being pulled from a database, and through C# to output in the HTML format.  The site.js script does contain more that the three functions, I have disabled what I do not need to get the site function for my testing.
   If I had to guess I do have the code wrong, but I cannot determine where I have errors in the code.
   The complete working being done can be seen at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MikeRM2/d5gopkw2/35/

The following are the first two functions for this:

```
 function changefc(e) {
    e.checked = false;
    console.log(e);
    return e;
 }

function changefd(evt) {
   evt.disabled = true;
   console.log(evt);
   return evt;
}
```

The above are called in the following function and I am passing variables into them to change the state of the variable.  The following is the code to work through the web page:

```
 console.log("beforeBind");
 $(".cbFS").on('click', updateDisabledState);

 function updateDisabledState() {
   console.log("on update")

   //This is to set the grid to the correct settings on load.
   //Get the elements of the main grid.
   var qSelAll = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('.MainGrid').children);
   for (var a = 0; a < qSelAll.length; a++) {
    //Check the factions grid
       var gridFac = $('.factionGrid');
       for (var b = 0; b < gridFac.length; b++) {
       //Check if the Faction is set.  If it is set then allow the data to be processed.
       //If it is not set then set all the Reputations Levels to false and disable them.
           var gridFS = [].slice.call(gridFac[b].querySelectorAll('.cbFS'));
           var repGrid = [].slice.call(gridFac[b].querySelectorAll('.repLevelGrid .cbRS'));
           for (var c = 0; c < gridFS.length; c++) {
               console.log(c);
               console.log(gridFS[c]);
               var fieldFS = gridFS[c].checked;
               if (fieldFS === false) {
                  for (var d = 0; d < repGrid.lengrh; d++) {
                  console.log(d);
                  console.log(repGrid[d]);
                  var fieldRSc = repGrid[d].checked;
                  var fieldRSd = repGrid[d].disabled;
                  changefc(fieldRSc);
                  changefd(fieldRSd);
                  console.log(fieldRSc);
                  console.log(fieldRSd);
                  }
               } else {
                  continue;
               }
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

What I get from here is nothing happening on the page.  When I uncheck the outer checkbox behind the name, the inner checkboxes in the table do not change state.  With the outer unselected, all the inner checkboxes on that "row" of the table should uncheck and disable.  If the outer checkbox is checked on load or by selection, the inner checkboxes should be checking each other to determine if they should be checked or not.
As can be seen in the top inner table everything should be unchecked and disabled.  It is not, the first checkbox is unchecked, the next three are checked, and the last two are unchecked, but they are still all enabled.
In the bottom inner table, the last checkbox is checked but the previous checkbox is unchecked, so that last one should be unchecked and disabled.

Comment: Your JSFiddle example is invalid.  [**Html IDs must be unique**.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: The Html IDs are being auto generated.  Not sure how I could change them.  As everything is being placed on the page dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add a class to the checkboxes that you wish to be checked by default when the master checkboxes are checked.

The jquery below will search for any checkboxes within the parent `tr` (table row) and then act upon them. You have already added the class `.cbFS` for the master checkboxes so I have used this as the identifier for them, and then used your existing class `.cbRS` for the associated checkboxes.

I added a new class `.default-checked` to the associated checkboxes that should, by default, be checked.

This is done within a custom function so that it can be run after a master checkbox value has changed, but also once the document is ready.

**Erik Phillips is correct though, your HTML `id` for each element should be unique or you will get into some bother later on.**

Let me know if this isn't what you needed.

```js
// Run when document is ready
$(document).ready( function() {

  // Cycle through each of the master checkboxes
  $(".cbFS").each(function() {

    // Check if it is checked or not, and run the custom function
    if (this.checked) {
      checkCheckboxes($(this), "");
    } else {
      checkCheckboxes($(this), "disabled");
    }
  
  });

});


// Add event for any change of the checkboxes with class .cbFS, as above check if checked and then run custom function
$(".cbFS").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    checkCheckboxes($(this), "");
  } else {
    checkCheckboxes($(this), "disabled");
  }
});


function checkCheckboxes(master, disabled) {

  // Check if the checkboxes should be disabled
  if (disabled != "disabled") {

    // Find closest row and then enable any checkboxes with class .cbRS 
    master.closest("tr").find(".cbRS").prop('disabled', disabled);
    // Again, find closest row and check any checkboxes with the class .default-checked
    master.closest("tr").find(".default-checked").prop('checked', true);

  } else {

    // Find closest row, find any checkbox with class .cbRS. Uncheck these checkboxes and disable them
    master.closest("tr").find(".cbRS").prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', disabled);

  }


}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color:#C05046">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 Maingrid">
      <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="factionGrid">
              <td class="hidden">1</td>
              <td class="hidden">1</td>
              <td>Ale Association</td>
              <td class="col-md-1">
                <input name="FactionSet" class="cbFS" id="FactionSet" type="checkbox" data-val-required="The FactionSet field is required." data-val="true" value="true" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="form-group RepLevelGrid">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="">
                      <table>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">6</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" data-val-required="The ReputationIsChecked field is required." data-val="true" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Enemy</td>
                            <td class="hidden">0</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">13</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS default-checked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Neutral</td>
                            <td class="hidden">1</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">1</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS default-checked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Acquaintance</td>
                            <td class="hidden">2</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">8</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS default-checked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Friend</td>
                            <td class="hidden">3</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">2</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Ally</td>
                            <td class="hidden">4</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">11</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Kindred</td>
                            <td class="hidden">5</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="factionGrid">
              <td class="hidden">1</td>
              <td class="hidden">2</td>
              <td>Men of Ened</td>
              <td class="col-md-1">
                <input name="FactionSet" class="cbFS" id="FactionSet" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="form-group RepLevelGrid">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="">
                      <table>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">13</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS default-checked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Neutral</td>
                            <td class="hidden">1</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">1</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS default-checked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Acquaintance</td>
                            <td class="hidden">2</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">8</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS default-checked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Friend</td>
                            <td class="hidden">3</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">2</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Ally</td>
                            <td class="hidden">4</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="hidden">11</td>
                            <td>
                              <input name="ReputationIsChecked" class="cbRS default-checked" id="ReputationIsChecked" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" />
                            </td>
                            <td>Kindred</td>
                            <td class="hidden">5</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works for the first part of my problem.  Though the ".default-checked" doesn't necessarily matter, nothing is by default checked in these grids.  I did have a problem when I pushed it through Visual Studio, but I figured it out... instead of ".cbRS" I put ".cbFS" which wasn't enabling the boxes.  Figured that out and it works.  Though it has not addressed the second part which is within the ".cbRS" of each section, with disabling a checkbox if the previous is not checked.  I might have something for that, if I work it a little more.

Comment: Not quite understanding you... When one of the `.cbFS` checkboxes is checked then the associated `.cbRS` checkboxes are enabled, when `.cbFS` is unchecked then they `.cbRS` are disabled. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Yes that was what I was looking for in part.  That is also what your answer helped with.  I was also looking at within each section cycling through the ".cbRS" checkboxes to determine if the previous one was checked, and if it wasn't checked disabling that checkbox.  The ".cbFS" checkbox enables the ".cbRS" checkboxes, but the ".cbRS" checkboxes also enable each other.  But I can work with what I currently have.  Your answer helped tremendously, and I thank you for it.

Comment: I figured out what I was looking for with cycling of the `.cbRS` checkboxes.  I have a function that works in preventing the use of a checkbox if the previous one has not been selected.  Though I tried it two different ways, the creation of a new function worked better than the reuse of an older function.  Even though they are the same.  Was also able to get the names and id tags to be correct.  Can be seen at the above JSFiddle.